# Pyarrow slice pushdown for Azure data lake

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-lake, pyarrow, apache-arrow

I want to access Parquet files on an Azure data lake, and only retrieve some rows.

Here is a reproducible example, using a public dataset:

```
import pyarrow.dataset as ds
from adlfs import AzureBlobFileSystem

abfs_public = AzureBlobFileSystem(
    account_name="azureopendatastorage")

dataset_public = ds.dataset('az://nyctlc/yellow/puYear=2010/puMonth=1/part-00000-tid-8898858832658823408-a1de80bd-eed3-4d11-b9d4-fa74bfbd47bc-426339-18.c000.snappy.parquet', filesystem=abfs_public)
```

The processing time is the same for collecting 5 rows compared to collecting the full dataset. Is there a way to achieve slice pushdown using Pyarrow?

Here are my tests:

```
dataset_public.to_table()
# 5min 30s

dataset_public.head(5)
# 5min 11s

dataset_public.scanner().head(5)
# 5min 43s
```

I'm not sure if there is a difference between `.head()` and `.scanner().head()`

Related pages:

- Apache Arrow website: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html#reading-from-cloud-storage
- ADLFS Github page: https://github.com/fsspec/adlfs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a few tweaks, I think I got what you were looking for. First, let's look at the original code you posted:

```py
import pyarrow.dataset as ds
from adlfs import AzureBlobFileSystem

abfs_public = AzureBlobFileSystem(
    account_name="azureopendatastorage")

dataset_public = ds.dataset('az://nyctlc/yellow/puYear=2010/puMonth=1/part-00000-tid-8898858832658823408-a1de80bd-eed3-4d11-b9d4-fa74bfbd47bc-426339-18.c000.snappy.parquet', filesystem=abfs_public)
```

Looking at the path you provided, you're pointing it a single file instead of the whole dataset. Adding a couple tweaks:

```py
import pyarrow.dataset as ds
from adlfs import AzureBlobFileSystem

abfs_public = AzureBlobFileSystem(account_name="azureopendatastorage")
dataset_public = ds.dataset('nyctlc/yellow/', filesystem=abfs_public, partitioning='hive')
```

Now, using `dataset_public.head(5)` I get:

[image: Screenshot VSCode Jupyter]

Since I didn't give it a sort order, it just grabbed the first 5 rows it could get from whatever file happened to be the first fragment (most likely).

In your original code example, the path you gave was using `puYear=2010` and `puMonth=1`, so we can use those. Because we told it to use `hive` partitioning, we can confirm that it picked up that the dataset is partitioned on these values:

```py
print(dataset_public.partitioning.schema)
# prints:
# puYear: int32
# puMonth: int32
# -- schema metadata --
# org.apache.spark.sql.parquet.row.metadata: '{"type":"struct","fields":[{"' + 1456
```

And if we get the first 5 rows using those fields as a filter:

[image: get filtered rows]

So that took 1min and 31s. But we can do better than that!

[image: batch_size = 5]

W00t! 1.12s

See, the default batch_size is pretty large, I forget what it is offhand right now. But if you only want to grab a small number of rows you can adjust the batch_size and fragment readahead size etc. To better fit your use case.

If you look at the base API documentation for the `head()` method, it has `**kwargs` that says "see scanner() method for full parameter description". And if you go to the `scanner()` method, it points you here: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.dataset.Scanner.html#pyarrow.dataset.Scanner.from_dataset where you can see all of the available parameters to the method. Like getting only a subset of columns (very efficient because Parquet):

[image: column filter]

I hope this helps you understand better how to leverage the dataset APIs and the rough edges / tricks to improving performance.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for!

One question to ensure I understand: as you show, setting the batch_size considerably improves performances. 

are there situations where I should not set the batch size to be equal to the number of rows I want to retrieve? Or I should always use it when using pulling few rows with head()

Comment: It's likely going to depend on the filesystem you're pulling from. If it's a high-latency filesystem like S3 or ADLS, and the individual file is potentially very large, you probably should set the batch_size pretty low if you're just doing `head`. However, if you're using a filter that isn't just the partitioned columns, it could be detrimental to have a low batch size if most of the rows would get filtered out since you'll do more round trips that way. As with many things in this space, it's a balance.

Answer (score 1):

It took more than 5 minutes 6:57 mins for me to load the public data set with slice pushdown refer below:-

```py
import pyarrow.dataset as ds

from adlfs import AzureBlobFileSystem

  

abfs_public = AzureBlobFileSystem(

account_name="azureopendatastorage")

  

dataset_public = ds.dataset('az://nyctlc/yellow/puYear=2010/puMonth=1/part-00000-tid-8898858832658823408-a1de80bd-eed3-4d11-b9d4-fa74bfbd47bc-426339-18.c000.snappy.parquet', filesystem=abfs_public)

  

scanner = dataset_public.scanner()

table = scanner.to_table()

subset_table = table.slice(0, 5)

print(subset_table)
```

**Output :-**

[image]

[image]

It appears that gathering 5 rows of data takes the same amount of time as gathering the entire dataset. ***Because, The pyarrow.dataset module does not include slice pushdown method, the full dataset is first loaded into memory before any rows are filtered.***

As a workaround, You can make use of **Pyspark** that processed the result faster refer below:-

Code :-

```py
# Azure storage access info
blob_account_name = "azureopendatastorage"
blob_container_name = "nyctlc"
blob_relative_path = "yellow"
blob_sas_token = "r"

# Allow SPARK to read from Blob remotely
wasbs_path = 'wasbs://%s@%s.blob.core.windows.net/%s' % (blob_container_name, blob_account_name, blob_relative_path)
spark.conf.set(
  'fs.azure.sas.%s.%s.blob.core.windows.net' % (blob_container_name, blob_account_name),
  blob_sas_token)
print('Remote blob path: ' + wasbs_path)

# SPARK read parquet, note that it won't load any data yet by now
df = spark.read.parquet(wasbs_path)
print('Register the DataFrame as a SQL temporary view: source')
df.createOrReplaceTempView('source')

# Display top 10 rows
print('Displaying top 10 rows: ')
display(spark.sql('SELECT * FROM source LIMIT 10'))
```

**Output:-**

[image]

**Reference :-**

[azure-docs/dataset-taxi-yellow.md at main · MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs · GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/open-datasets/dataset-taxi-yellow.md)

Comment: thanks for your reply @SiddheshDesai. The Pyarrow dataset page (https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/dataset.html#tabular-datasets) says that Pyarrow is able to do predicate pushdown (filtering rows), and that is why I am wondering how to achieve it. 

When you say that the Pyarrow dataset does not include slice pushdown, you read that in one of the Pyarrow docs? Or you are guessing that from the tests?

I see that in your tests, you are doing `.to_table()`. I thought that `to_table()` collects the data, so it already downloads everything

Comment: And for Spark, I think it's a good backup solution. I will use the Arrow format for data modification later, so I'd prefer to skip converting to Spark and then back to Arrow. 

But if that is the only solution, then yes it's a possibility that works